# Activate WorkOrder object with project-scratch-def.json file

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org-definition-file, work-order

I'm trying to define my project-scratch-def.json file to enable the standard `WorkOrder` object, it appears the object is enabled under the Field Service section of the setup menu. I added the `FieldService` feature, however that does not appear to enable the object or the section of the setup menu. Based on Salesforce's [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm), I would suspect `FieldService` is a valid feature and would enable the `WorkOrder` object. I'm mainly looking for a way to enable the standard object `WorkOrder`, so if there is another way of doing this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Salesforce Support:

> Meanwhile, you can include "FieldService" in the feature.
>
> FieldServiceSettings is available via Metadata API and thence also in the settings portion of the SFDX config -
>
> Try including fieldServiceOrgPref to true to actually activate the feature, while the feature's entry just makes it available.

The `FieldService` feature simply allows the Field Service settings in the environment, while the `fieldServiceSettings` and `fieldServiceOrgPref` settings enables the features in the environment.

Support also referenced the [metadata API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm) as keys for defining the `scratch-def.json` file. For this specific scenario, the [fieldServiceSettings documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_fieldservicesettings.htm) explains the settings to enable the `workOrder` object.